# How can I get Loadbalancer Name of azure vm using powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-load-balancer

I'm new on azure deployment, so we are trying to get a name on the current Virtual machine to make a deployment so we need to remove and put on rotation current virtual machine.

Today I was able to remove a VM of the balancer but not put on rotation.

I know that I need the name of the balancer.

Now I was able to get:
Ip-Address.
Name of nic.
Name on azure of the VM.
Name of subscription.

I got code below on powershell code that set on rotation:

```
$nic = Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $NicName -ResourceGroup $RGName 
$lb = Get-AzureRmLoadBalancer -Name $Namelb -ResourceGroupName $RGlb
$nic.IpConfigurations[0].LoadBalancerBackendAddressPools = $lb.BackendAddressPools 
Set-AzureRmNetworkInterface -NetworkInterface $nic
```

But I have no the name of the balancer.

And on this way I was able to remove

```
$nic = Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $NicName -ResourceGroup $RGName 
$lb = Get-AzureRmLoadBalancer -Name $Namelb -ResourceGroupName $RGlb
$nic.IpConfigurations[0].LoadBalancerBackendAddressPools = $lb.BackendAddressPools 
Set-AzureRmNetworkInterface -NetworkInterface $nic
```

If I have another information but Name of balancer not.

What can I do for getting this name of balancer?

Thanks,

Marco Carballo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have added a VM to the load balancer, then you want to get the name of the load balancer, you could try the command below, the `$Namelb` will be the name of the load balancer.

```
$NicName = "<name of the NIC>"
$RGName = "<resource group name>"
$nic = Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $NicName -ResourceGroup $RGName 
$a = $nic.IpConfigurations[0].LoadBalancerBackendAddressPools.Id -split"/"
$Namelb = $a[8]
```

[image]

Besides, if you have removed the VM from the load balancer, you could just use the command below to list all the load balancers in the resource group or subscription and find that one you want.

List via resource group:

```
Get-AzureRmLoadBalancer -ResourceGroupName <resource group name> | Select-Object Name
```

List via subscription:

```
Get-AzureRmLoadBalancer | Select-Object Name
```

Comment: Awesome @Joy Wang, I test it and it Works Great and Chingon. Thanks a lot.